# Handle a file that can have suspicious macros when passed over HTTP request

Tags: python, django

Suppose a user is trying to upload a file that contains macros to the server (I am using the Django server). How can I handle or check whether the file contains macros inside it without opening or writing the file to the server. I am using [oletools](https://pypi.org/project/oletools/) for detecting macros.

The problem is, whenever a file is uploaded using the POST method, the URL is bound to a view "upload-doc". Inside the view I want to detect the macros. But as the file is still in HTTP request (not written to the server yet) the type of the file is "InMemoryUploadFile" which means I guess it is still in memory, not written to disk.

Now, how can I detect the macros in this file which is not yet written to the disk? From [this](https://bitbucket.org/decalage/oletools/wiki/olevba) example on using olevba, I have to pass the file path for detecting macros, but as the file is in memory, I am getting "FileNotFound" error.

Is there any way to detect macros in a file without accessing or writing to the server when it is uploaded using HTTP POST request?

I am open to using any other package in achieving this. ANy suggestions can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to actually run the command-line olevba script? That won't work, but, glancing at the source code, you can just import the library directly and pass a ["file-like object"](https://github.com/decalage2/oletools/blob/203c40afc57b41c2a08a2a3df2c8a549e295ea38/oletools/olevba.py#L2616), which `InMemoryUploadFile` should be.

Comment: I am not running it through command-line. I have imported the library and passed the "InMemoryUploadFIle" object for macros detection. But the library is giving "FileNotFoundError". In fact the library wants the file path of the uploaded file.